# Help identifying 6-circuit PCB header socket

Tags: pcb, connector, ribbon-cable

This is from a JVC TD R272 tape deck.

[image: Broken off connector]

An FFC (Flat Flex cable) from the head to the board goes into it. I snapped it due to impatience.
Can someone tell me the name of the white PCB header socket?
It has six contacts on the base and the six conductor FFC slides into it.

The socket connector leaning against the PCB with the six contacts it sat into, some of the contacts are still in place.

[image: The connector on its side]

View of PCB from below:

[image: From below]

The remnants of the contacts on top.

[image: The remnants of the contacts]

The FFC that fits into the socket:

[image: End of FFC that slides into block]

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a header or possibly a connector with IDC pins, however your pictures are far from helpful. Show a picture of the mating connector or the at least the mating side of the connector. are there any markings on the connector?

Comment: You may find it easiest to replace this with some other sort of connection.  The nature of the ribbon will be as important to figuring that out as the broken pieces of connector.

Comment: please post pictures that show the actual pins ..... make sure that there is no reflection .... the second picture that you posted has reflection that obscures detail

Comment: I've added more, software is not playing ball. Thanks for help

Comment: Take a look at WM6444-ND https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0039532064/WM6444-ND/1870013 this would be an FFC connector. Can't tell from your pics though. If it is verttcal maybe something lime WM1175-ND https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0520300629/WM1175-ND/2242432

Comment: @PaulG You need to measure the size of the connector

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the pitch is on that cable, but I'm willing to bet it's 1mm

Maybe one like this:

[image]

[This one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/amphenol-fci/HLW6S-2C7LF/609-1819-ND/1002134)
[Or This one](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0520450645/WM14631-ND/3262771)
[Or these connectors](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/connectors-interconnects/ffc-fpc-flat-flexible-connectors/399?k=connector&k=&pkeyword=connector&pv69=80&sf=1&FV=ffe0018f%2C1600007&quantity=&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=500)

Comment: Thanks very much for answers, i think you nailed it with this https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-connector-corporation/52806-0610/WM5317-ND/2046767, will measure distance between contacts and buy this if right. thanks again :)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment